# Error querying the Rally API - DynamicJsonObject does not contain a definition for 'Errors'

Tags: c#, rally

I'm trying to query the search API of Rally, here is my c# code:

```
var searchRequest = new Request()
{
    ArtifactName = "search",
    Limit = 25,
    Project = "/project/" + CurrentProject,
    ProjectScopeDown = true,
    ProjectScopeUp = true,
    PageSize = 25,

    Fetch = new List<string>() { "true" }
};

searchRequest.AddParameter("keywords", "foo");
QueryResult queryTaskResult = api.Query(searchRequest);
```

this works as expected and returns result, however i want to pass a parameter of compact=true, which will return slightly different data (mainly a standard web link to the item).

```
var searchRequest = new Request()
{
    ArtifactName = "search",
    Limit = 25,
    Project = "/project/" + CurrentProject,
    ProjectScopeDown = true,
    ProjectScopeUp = true,
    PageSize = 25,

    Fetch = new List<string>() { "true" }
};

searchRequest.AddParameter("keywords", "foo");
///this is the new item
searchRequest.AddParameter("compact", "true");
QueryResult queryTaskResult = api.Query(searchRequest);
```

However when i fire this request I get the following error

```
Rally.RestApi.Json.DynamicJsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'Errors'
```

However when I try to do this request in the browser it works fine.

Any help as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

**Why do you want to do this?**

What I want to do is build up a link to the WEB view of the object, eg:
    https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/{CurrentProject}d/detail/{ObjectType}/{ObjectId}

I already know the CurrentProject, I need to know the ObjectType and the ObjectId

I have found, when i pass **compact=true**, the _ref provides this, **'/defect/1234567'** but this throws an exception.

If I do not pass **compact=true**, the _ref returns the API reference **'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.x/defect/1234567'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the compact functionality was added to WSAPI after the .NET toolkit was created and we've never updated it to support it.

I filed a github issue here: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/issues/37

compact=true was mainly a performance optimization to reduce the size of responses in large result sets.

Other than performance is there a reason you'd like to use it?

Comment: Hi @Kyle Morse, I've updated the question, I'm interested in the _ref to build up a link to the object in the search result

Comment: Sounds like you just need want the relative ref then.  There is a utility for that: http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/html/55789b3e-ce6a-486f-5726-14453e78cda1.htm